# Tell NSDocument that the document has been modified

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdocument

I'm writing a Document-Based App in OSX. I found when I change the contents of the doc, the app doesn't know the document has been changed. I can close the doc without warning, which causes my unsaved content to be lost.

How can I tell `NSDocument` that the document has been modified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`updateChangeCount:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDocument/updateChangeCount%3a) method with `NSChangeDone` as argument.